# Machine learning in R: Using MLR package survival filters in MLR3

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlr, mlr3

I want to run a number of machine learning algorithms with different feature selection methods on survival data using the MLR3 package. For that, I am using the Benchmark() function of MLR3.

Unfortunately, filter feature selection methods of MLR3 do not support survival, yet. However, MLR package supports survival filters.

I can fuse MLR learners with an MLR filter method. After that, I need to convert them to a learner in MLR3 in order to be able to use banchmark_grid() function of MLR3.

Is there  any way to use MLR survival filters in MLR3? Or is there any way that I can convert MLR filters to MLR3 filters?

Comment: Which filters are you missing? You can add a feature request in [mlr3filters](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3filters).

Comment: Unfortunately, all the survival filters are missing. Based on section 3.5.1 Calculating filter values of mlr3 book: "Currently, only classification and regression tasks are supported."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not -- the basic design of mlr and mlr3 is fundamentally different.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for your response. Would you know if there is any way that I can have something like benchmark_grid() of MLR3 in MLR? Basically, I do not want all the tasks to be considered for all learners. benchmark_grid() develops a data.frame that allows me to decide which rows I want to exclude from the benchmark. But, I don't see something like that in MLR.

Comment: In principle you can edit the benchmark design in the same way as for mlr. See https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/benchmark_experiments.html

Comment: Thanks, yes I have seen this webpage. In the benchmark() function they have used expand.grid() function to generate the design of the benchmark. So, possibly it cannot be modified.